# Clear Zero values in entire workbook (Either its in formula or value)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear the contents if cell value is zero ((Either its in formula or value) The below code is working by selection of cells, but i want to do this for entire workbook please help me to change the code.

```
Sub DelZeros()
  Dim c As Range

  For Each c In Selection
    If c.Value = 0 Then c.ClearContents
  Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Selection you could use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` And if you need to do it for all sheets in a workbook you could do sth like that

```
Sub DelAllZeros()
          Cells.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder _
            :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub


Sub DelFormulaZeros()

Dim rg As Range, sngCell As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim result As Long

    For Each sh In Worksheets

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rg = sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 1)
        result = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0

        If result = 0 Then
            For Each sngCell In rg
                If sngCell.Value = 0 Then
                    sngCell.ClearContents
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting Run time error the above code is not working

Comment: I added Sub and End Sub. Could you please specify the Run Time Error?

Comment: c.ClearContents

Comment: I am sorry but if you get an run time error then you usually an more specified error message

Comment: "we cant do that to a merged cell"

Comment: Ok, then use c.vallue = "" instead of c.ClearContens

Comment: Ok, I replaced the code withan excel built-in routine

Comment: Looks good to me, if you have any issues it would most probably be due to preceding / leading spaces. I'd just use wildcards to cover those scenarios: `What:="*0"`, `What:="0*"`, `What:="*0*"`

Comment: Thanks the new code is working for me without error. But its not clearing formula cells, can you help me to add those function also

Comment: Are you really sure you want to clear the formula cells? That means the formula will be deleted. Or do you just want not to see the 0 in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub DelAllZeros()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next

        ws.Cells.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        Set frange = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not frange Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In frange
                If c.Value = 0 Then
                    c.Formula = ClearContents
                End If
            Next c
        End If
        Set frange = Nothing
    Next ws
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: I have changed the above code to consider formula cell also. But this is working only in active sheet not entire workbook can anybody help to apply this code to entire workbook